# Does your reputation join with an old account if you merge them?

Tags: support, reputation, merge-accounts

If you merge two accounts, does the reputation join?

Answer (score 0):

If two accounts are merged, the target-account now owns all actions of both, including posting, editing and voting on comments, answer and questions.
And collects all the blame and praise for them.

Though the actions will be sanity-checked, so you cannot thereafter own multiple votes (up and/or down) on the same post/comment, nor any on yourself.

And then rep will be re-calculated, as if they were always one account, taking into account all the rules including daily cap.
The only artifact which might later give the game away to normal users would be any attributed action you did before the target-account was created...

Answer (score -1):

If there is no cross voting between the accounts then target account get the the sum of reputations of the two accounts.

If the total reputation earned by two accounts from votes on any day was greater than 200 then the target account will be left remaining reputation for these day, and this will subject to the daily rep limit.

So overall, total reputation is calculated based on certain rules, and you get new reputation(may be exact same as Add both or less)